# How do I get the bleeding edge Chromium?

Tags: installation, package-management, chromium

The following versions of Chromium are available at the moment :

- [Chromium Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/stable) (13.0.782.218)
- [Chromium Beta PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/beta) (14.0.835.126)
- [Ubuntu Repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/chromium-browser) (14.0.835.202)
- [Chromium Dev PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/dev) (15.0.865.0)
- [Chromium Daily PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa) (15.0.871.0)

All packages for Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot.

However, as per [Chromium Developer Calendar](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar), the following versions are released for Linux:

```
linux   dev     16.0.904.0
linux   beta    15.0.874.92
linux   stable  14.0.835.202
```

Is there any way I can get the latest developer build running on my system (without compiling it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Alternative Chromium PPA

The PPAs above are not being updated at all. Alex Shkop has taken up responsibility to keep a better, more updated PPA set for chromium. They include:

- [Chromium Stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Ea-v-shkop/+archive/chromium) (currently at *21.0.1180.79*)
- [Chromium Dev](https://launchpad.net/%7Ea-v-shkop/+archive/chromium-dev) (currently at *23.0.1246*)

**Note**: The above PPAs are only for 12.04 at the moment.

### Bleeding Edge Chromium Binaries

You can download the continuous builds from [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html). This will get you the last bleeding-edge chromium revision which passed the test suite.

To install them, just extract the zip file somewhere (I use `~/apps/`) and run the `chrome` binary inside.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you found the right place to get them, but they were just not up to date, the Chromium daily PPA has been restarted.