# Want to find out how to install lastest chromium build

Tags: chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the bleeding edge Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68571/how-do-i-get-the-bleeding-edge-chromium)

I want to know how to install the latest chromium build on my computer, I've checked the ppa and it only goes up to 18.0.997.0 whilst the newest version is Chromium 18.0.1011.0

Comment: If you update you'll get the lastest versoin it's been uploaded to the ppa. (I've got it now)